# Look for superabsorbent balls whose expansion is reversible

Tags: absorption

I am glad to find very cheap superabsorbent balls (see image below). However, I found their expansion is **not** reversible. The wiki entry 'Superabsorbent polymer' also says that the material will '**retain**' extremely large amounts of a liquid relative to their own mass. 
[image]
[image]

Is there any other superabsorbent material whose expansion is reversible? If yes, is it available as tiny balls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.** The ones I have are known commercially as Jelly Marbles or Orbeez. They're sold at gardening stores, home decor, and online. They're used as [toys](http://orbeezone.com/index.php/) but also as gardening products that absorb excess moisture in wet conditions and supply water in dry conditions. Mine grow up to about 1.5cm from a starting diameter of ~0.1cm. I've been told that some grow up to ~7.5cm; and they're advertised as increasing by 100-300 times in volume at full saturation. The process is reversible (e.g. by putting them in a cup with a wad of paper towels). I use them as a drying agent where powdered $\ce{CaCl2}$ etc. aren't ideal.

Note the actual identity of the polymer in the beads is a trade-secret, so I don't think you'll be able to find that information.